# Location based services in android

Tags: android

please guide me about how i can build an android app which can find the hotels or shopping mall according to my current location . I have gone through several tutorials but only what i can do is to find the latitude and longitude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a POI (point of interest) collection in order to create this kind of application.

You can pay for such a service from professional sources. Otherwise you have to make your own options, such as using [Foursquare Venues](https://developer.foursquare.com/).